# How to load widget data from a specific category?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, widget

**I am an absolute beginner of Magento.**

Created a new page via `Content -> Pages`. On that page, I want to show the recent 10 T-shirts from the tees category. Therefore I included a widget but I can select that category specifically. All recent products are showing up. The particular product category ID is 41. Is there any way to alter and use this widget code to show products from the T-shirt category only? Here is the current code:

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" show_pager="0" products_count="10" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^]^]"}}
```

Thanks in advance